# TimeStamp in Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, timestamp

I am new to Swift, I want to parse JSON with TimeStamp but I have problem my timeStamp no found

It's my code :

```
  let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSinceNow)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func downloadPrograms(for timestamp: CVTimeStamp) {

            Alamofire.request("http://52.50.138.211:8080/ChanelAPI/programs/\(timestamp)").responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[PrograToDayModel]>) in

                let programlArray = response.result.value



                if let programlArray = programlArray {
                    for program in programlArray {

                        print(program.description as Any)
                    }

                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date/1779963-timeintervalsince1970) with current `Date` because [`timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date/1780473-timeintervalsincenow) with current `Date` return 0.

Now you need to put `downloadPrograms` out side the `viewDidLoad` with  your other class methods and change its parameter type to `NSNumber` because you are storing timestamp in `NSNumber` instance.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    self.downloadPrograms(for: timeStamp)
}

func downloadPrograms(for timestamp: NSNumber) {

    Alamofire.request("http://52.50.138.211:8080/ChanelAPI/programs/\(timestamp)").responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[PrograToDayModel]>) in

        let programlArray = response.result.value

        if let programlArray = programlArray {
            for program in programlArray {
                print(program.description as Any)
            }
        }
        //Reload tableView on main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well thank you but if I want to put a date a week or a month as I realize?

Comment: @КоляДудла Don't get your above comment what do you mean by "put a date a week or a month as I realize"?